# How to I switch to a git branch that ignores files without deleting these files?

Tags: git, gitignore

I have branch `master` that ignores `.idea` in its `.gitignore`.
From that, I created branch `noIgnore` that has no `.gitignore`.

I found that `checkout master` deletes `.idea`.

That's not the behavior I want. I want to keep `.idea`, just not track it, not on `master`. How do I do that?

Comment: If you're on `noIgnore` with `.idea` as a committed file, Git has no idea that you want to retain it (but ignore it) rather than delete it when you checkout a different branch.

Comment: In this case, maybe I should ask a different question: I want to ignore .idea most of the time, but occasionally I want to keep it, for backup as well as diff purposes, how do I accomplish that?

Comment: My first thought was to use two git repos on the same tree, but then I realized that .gitignore is per dir anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You could stop tracking changes for a file in repo

```
git update-index --skip-worktree .idea
```

Since you're tracking it in the other branch, then when you make changes you'll want to start tracking changes again

```
git update-index --no-skip-worktree .idea
```

When you get tired of doing this manually, you could create a post-checkout hook if on master, stop tracking, else start tracking.

Answer (score 0):

It removes .idea because that's what checkout does, it checks out master where there's no .idea. Try to add `--no-track` to your command.

Comment: Not sure what the relevance of `--no-track` is here - that's for preventing it from performing upstream tracking.